# Why is the Python IMAP library failing with Outlook?

Tags: python, email, office365

I'm trying to use Python to create a draft email programmatically in Office365. I have a similar code for Gmail that works fine. However, I'm getting the error `b'LOGIN failed.'`.

I thought the issue might be having 2FA enabled, but it's still not working with an app secret.

Here's my code excerpt:

```
import imaplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import pandas as pd
import random
import time

# Define IMAP server settings for Outlook
outlook_imap_server = 'outlook.office365.com'
outlook_imap_port = 993  # Port for SSL

# Set Outlook credentials
outlook_email = # email
outlook_password = # app secret

message = "hello"
utf8_message = message.as_bytes()

# Connect to Outlook IMAP server and save the email as draft
try:
    with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(outlook_imap_server, outlook_imap_port) as server:
        server.login(outlook_email, outlook_password)
        server.append('"Drafts"', None, imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), utf8_message)
    print("success")
except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the actual traceback

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online